# String Function To Get Right 1000, From the Last Period or Carriage return

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder

My question is a follow-up to a question that was asked and answered under another thread. However, the question not asked was how do you extract the remaining characters after the first 1000 or nearest '.' :

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121206/string-function-to-get-left-1000-but-only-to-last-period-or-carriage-return/324359?noredirect=1#comment632652_324359

I am trying to write the reverse side of this query (shown below) which will allow me to flow data from one section in a report builder report to another. The query below (written by Solomon Rutzky) pulls the first 1000 characters or to the nearest '.'. It works perfectly.

```sql
LEFT(LEFT(@Text, 1000),
 1001 - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(LEFT(@Text, 1000))))
```

What I currently have is:

```sql
declare @Text varchar(max) = '*Up unpacked friendly ecstatic so possible humoured do. Ample ended might folly quiet one set spoke her. We no am former valley assure. Four need spot ye said we find mile. Are commanded him convinced dashwoods did estimable forfeited. Shy celebrated met sentiments she reasonably but. Proposal its disposed eat advanced marriage sociable. Drawings led greatest add subjects endeavor gay remember. Principles one yet assistance you met impossible. The who arrival end how fertile enabled. Brother she add yet see minuter natural smiling article painted. Themselves at dispatched interested insensible am be prosperous reasonably it. She boisterous use friendship she dissimilar considered expression. Sex quick arose mrs lived. Mr things do plenty others an vanity myself waited to. Always parish tastes at as mr father dining at. Led ask possible mistress relation elegance eat likewise debating.

Or am nothing amongst chiefly address. The its enable direct men depend highly. Ham windows sixteen who inquiry fortune demands.

Is be upon sang fond must shew. Really boy law county she unable her sister. Feet you off its like like six. Among sex are leave law built now. In built table in an rapid blush. Merits behind on afraid or warmly. In either so spring wished. Melancholy wayBy message*';

with cte as (
    Select
        LEN(@Text) C,
        LEN(@Text) - 1000 Var,
        LEFT(LEFT(@Text, 1000), 1001 - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(LEFT(@Text, 1000)))) Narrative,
        RIGHT(Substring(@Text, 1000, 296), CHARINDEX('.', LEFT(@Text, 296))) Cntd,
        @Text Text
)
Select
    *,
    RIGHT(RIGHT(@Text, 1000), Var - CharIndex('.', Right(@Text, + Var))) Continued
from CTE
```

I determined `LEN` for the `@Text` and it is 1296. I then created `Var` to allow me to see what the `LEN` was for the remaining text.

'Narrative' gives me the first 1000 or nearest '.' and it worked perfectly. It provides a full sentence *The its enable direct men depend highly.* The second line of the second paragraph.

In *Continued*, I tried to take up at the end of the 1000 characters or nearest (.). Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exact output do you _expect_ for `Continued`? The requirement is not clear to me (from the attempted query or the final paragraph). Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Yitzhak, under the heading of ‘What I currently have :’ this is where I have shared the code I am using at this time to work on this problem. If copied into SMS and run, you will see the results I am working with. I felt this would be cleaner and more efficient than providing INSERT scripts. 

Desired out come is that the query I am attempting to write will provide all text after the point where the Narrative leaves off. My work in progress is listed as Continued. 

SQL Server is what I am currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

When I use the query: LEFT(LEFT(@Text, 1000), 1001 - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(LEFT(@Text, 1000))))  Narrative, against the paragraph that is in the declare statement, it allows me to extract the first 1000 characters or to the nearest period.

Using this, the last line of extracted text is ‘The its enable direct men depend highly.’

What I am trying to figure out is how to create another query that will take up where the 1000 characters or period stops, and will begin with the next line which is ‘Ham windows sixteen who inquiry fortune demands.’ and will continue until the end of the text.

In my efforts so far I have managed to get it to start from the next paragraph down which begins with ‘Is be upon … ‘.

I should be home for the evening, and will continue to work on this. However any advice would be appreciated.

I am on SQL 2019.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.
You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you to those who commented and those who have challenged me.** In the hope of sharing, I have a better explanation of the problem and I have included the solution within this response.

I am working on a report where the narrative needs to fit within a set space on a report. The report is being built using Microsoft Report Builder.

If the narrative exceeds the space it needs to overflow into a different document.

The first part of the puzzle was to extract part of the narrative that will fit within the face sheet. The solution for this comes from:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121206/string-function-to-get-left-1000-but-only-to-last-period-or-carriage-return/324359?noredirect=1#comment632652_324359

The second part of the puzzle is to then extract the remaining narrative so it can be added to a different document.

I am running SQL 2019.

I have included the query with a `DECLARE` statement that contains the sample narrative below. As a result there are no `INSERT` scripts included for duplication. Just copy/paste the code below to test.

Included is the solution to the second part of the problem and the extraction of the narrative which will be in a different document.

```
Declare @Text Varchar(max) = '*Up unpacked friendly ecstatic so possible humoured do. Ample ended might folly quiet one set spoke her. We no am former valley assure. Four need spot ye said we find mile. Are commanded him convinced dashwoods did estimable forfeited. Shy celebrated met sentiments she reasonably but. Proposal its disposed eat advanced marriage sociable. Drawings led greatest add subjects endeavor gay remember. Principles one yet assistance you met impossible. The who arrival end how fertile enabled. Brother she add yet see minuter natural smiling article painted. Themselves at dispatched interested insensible am be prosperous reasonably it. She boisterous use friendship she dissimilar considered expression. Sex quick arose mrs lived. Mr things do plenty others an vanity myself waited to. Always parish tastes at as mr father dining at. Led ask possible mistress relation elegance eat likewise debating.

Or am nothing amongst chiefly address. The its enable direct men depend highly. Ham windows sixteen who inquiry fortune demands.

Is be upon sang fond must shew. Really boy law county she unable her sister. Feet you off its like like six. Among sex are leave law built now. In built table in an rapid blush. Merits behind on afraid or warmly. In either so spring wished. Melancholy wayBy message*';

With CTE As 
(
Select
   /* allows me to see LEN of the Narrative I am using */
   LEN(@Text) CharacterCount,
   /* allows me to see approx LEN of the Narrative that will flow into the second document */
   LEN(@Text) - 1000 Var,
   /* allows me to proof read the results in report builder to compare the full uncut narrative with the Start and Ending Narrative */
   @Text FullNarrative,
   /* Solution to Part 1: This code below was a written by Stack Exchange Contributor Solomon Rutzky. The PATINDEX values were expanded upon. 
      This provides the start of the Narrative to a breaking point of either 1000 characters or a specified nearest character. */
   LEFT(LEFT(@Text, 1000), 1001 - PATINDEX('%[ .,!?;-]%', REVERSE(LEFT(@Text, 1000)))) StartNarrative    
)
Select
   *,
   /* Solution to Part 2: This extracts the ending part of the Narrative which overflows. Thank you CS! */ 
   TRIM(RIGHT(@Text,CharacterCount - LEN(StartNarrative))) AS EndNarrative
From CTE
```